# Синонимизировать [asynctask] и [android-asynctask]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

[android-asynctask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-asynctask) исключает двойственное значение, в тоже время с меткой [asynctask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynctask) намного больше вопросов и все они в контексте Android.

Нужно бы их синонимизировать. Вопрос только, в чью пользу?

Comment: Не все, есть 14 вопросов про Java и C#. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynctask+-android

Comment: @NickVolynkin там почти все вопросы по Java на самом деле в контексте Android. Метки не проставили просто.

Comment: @NickVolynkin А сможете данный вопрос решить хоть в какую-то пользу (хотя, скорей всего, логичнее было бы в пользу [tag:android-asyntask])? А то так было бы лучше, чем никак.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я совсем не шарю в андроиде. Может, ЮрийСПб тут будет более подходящим человеком. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin да эта метка как и другие вроде [tag:android-fragment]. Я не ЮрийСПб, но, имхо, за [tag:android-asynctask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метки успешно синонимизированы

Answer (score 6):

Голосую за [android-asynctask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-asynctask) как основную. Дело в том, что [asynctask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynctask) довольно часто используют для .NET вопросов, хоть я там уже и описание подправлял. А так будут сразу видеть, что эта метка относится к другой платформе, и выбирать более подходящую.

Answer (score 1):

Я голосую за `asynctask`, поскольку если вопрос задаётся в конексте android, то должна ставиться соответствующая метка (`android`).